Image processing optimisation in python
I am facing a speed problem with one of my function:
the idea is to simplify a color drawing (made on procreate) for later contour detections.
First i do Kmeans to find the rgb values of main colors of the drawing.
Then i pass my cleaning function to "clean" the image and transform every pixels which isn't a main color to the rgb closest main color.
It was pretty fast but it did weird things. Indeed for exemple between light blue and black colors i had dark blue colors which normaly wasn't there first.
here is an exemple of before after with
before image process
after image process (middle blue appears as it is an other main color)
Then i decided to only check localy around the pixel for the main colors and then choose the rgb closest one. I even tough i could process with 25 by 25 pixels area and if there is a variant zoom in at 5 by 5 pixel but it isn't any faster.
Also this method is waayyy more ressources intesive and my images are taking ages to process.
For my pc (R7 6800H and RTX 3060) it takes approximately 3 minutes for a 1000x2000pixel image
image to process (cute cat i made)
Here is what i actually search as a result:
goal
Here is the code of my function below.
Is there a way to be more efficient ? Do i miss a library or a easier way to do it ?
Thanks for your help :)
def clean_image_optimized(image_np, clustered_image, main_colors_rgb):
    
    print("Start Time:", datetime.datetime.now())

    #prepare data
    cleaned_image = np.copy(clustered_image)
    total_pixels = image_np.shape[0] * image_np.shape[1]
    block_size = 5  # Initial block size for the first pass
    region_size = 5  # Neighborhood size for detailed checking

    main_colors_set = set(tuple(color) for color in main_colors_rgb)

    #first  check in larg blocks
    for y in range(0, image_np.shape[0], block_size):
        for x in range(0, image_np.shape[1], block_size):
            
            #block region
            y_max = min(image_np.shape[0], y + block_size)
            x_max = min(image_np.shape[1], x + block_size)
            block = image_np[y:y_max, x:x_max, :3]

            # Check if the block is homogeneous (all pixels are the same)
            unique_colors_in_block = np.unique(block.reshape(-1, 3), axis=0)

            if all(tuple(color) in main_colors_set for color in unique_colors_in_block):

                #entire block composed main color, continue without modification
                continue
            else:
                #check more precisely
                for i in range(y, y_max):
                    for j in range(x, x_max):
                        pixel_color = image_np[i, j, :3]
                        if tuple(pixel_color) not in main_colors_set:
                            
                            y_min, y_max_i = max(0, i - region_size), min(image_np.shape[0], i + region_size)
                            x_min, x_max_j = max(0, j - region_size), min(image_np.shape[1], j + region_size)
                            region = clustered_image[y_min:y_max_i, x_min:x_max_j]
                            region_flat = region.reshape(-1, 3) 
                            unique, counts = np.unique(region_flat, axis=0, return_counts=True)
                            dominant_color = unique[np.argmax(counts)]
                            cleaned_image[i, j] = dominant_color
        
    print("End Time:", datetime.datetime.now())

    return cleaned_image


In Python, you should really avoid loops to get fast code because the standard implementation, CPython, is a (slow) interpreter. Sometimes this is not possible and solutions are to use compilation-based modules like Cython or Numba. Sometimes they are not enough and it is better to use native languages (eg. C, C++, Rust, etc.)

Besides, be aware that Numpy is not suited for computing small arrays or ones where the main dimension is small (if the contiguous one is small, this is not great either). On top of that, please note that np.unique is pretty expensive because it performs an (expensive generic)  sort. Numpy 2.0 can be significantly faster for that though it is still quite expensive.

Regarding the algorithm, Kmeans seems a bit overkill to me : isn't an histogram enough?

Last but not least, you mention your GPU but this Python code cannot benefit from it. Numpy does not benefit from GPUs. In fact, it does not benefit from multiple cores (except BLAS functions). Libraries like OpenCV can (if configured properly). This assume the code is vectorized though and operate on large arrays. CPython loops generally makes codes using GPUs much slower (because of unneeded synchronizations and data transfers).

Oh, and note it is better to provide a minimal working example so people can play with your code and write better answers ;)

First of all, why do you need color reduction for contour detection? Although color reduction does not seem to make much difference to the human eye, it can definitely distort contours, which can have a negative impact on the accuracy of contour detection. That being said, if you really need color reduction, I recommend Pillow. I don't know if it will give you the result you want, but it is very fast.
